# How can I include an image into a chapter title in memoir?

Tags: graphics, memoir

I am so sorry if this has already been asked and answered, but I am really struggling to find an answer that doesn't give me lots of error messages.
I am using memoir to typeset a booklet. I have done this before several times to get friends' books ready for print but now I am stuck as I have been asked to include an image in each chapter title!
Is there a way to have a picture on the left side of each chapter title? (see picture for what it should ideally look like)
So far, this is what I have for chapters (I have % the lines that I normally use but had to get rid of the 'chapter X' because this will be replaced by said image.)

```
\makechapterstyle{Tufte}{ % Define a new chapter style
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{\null \vskip-0.8\onelineskip} % Whitespace before the chapter starts
\addto\captionsnorsk{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Dag}}
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{} % "Chapter" text font specification
%\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\Large\itshape\chaptername} % "Chapter" text font specification
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{} % Chapter number font specification
%\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\LARGE\thechapter \\} % Chapter number font specification
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{} % Space between the chapter number and text
 \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{ % Chapter title font specification
    \raggedright
    \itshape\Huge{##1}}
    \renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{
    \vskip1.5\onelineskip
    }}
    \chapterstyle{Tufte} % Set the chapter style to the custom style defined above
```

I am very grateful for any answers!
X

[image: this is where the image should be positioned in the chapter title]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```latex
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{your_image_here}}
```

just before each `\chapter{...}`.

If you want to lower the image, you may add a raisebox with a negative length, i.e.,

```latex
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\raisebox{-3ex}{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{snowman-vectorial}}}
```

Of course, you have to adapt the image height and raisebox length argument.

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much!! You've made my day! Can I ask a follow-up question: The image does not appear when I omit the chapter number, so \chapter*{Introduksjon}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduksjon}. Is there a way to add the image in these too? Thank you again!!

Comment: Similar as above, but instead of redefining `\printchaptername` redefine both `\printchapternum` and `\printchapternonum`.

Comment: a thousand thanks!